# Server Date and Time on Action In SSJS

Tags: xpages

I want your help to get Server Date and Time when action is performed. e.g. Submit, Approve, Reject etc

```
var myDoc:NotesDocument = data_source.getDocument().
```

I have tried following but failed to get server time this always stores client date and time specially when its executed on client.

```
myDoc.replaceItemValue("ApprovedOn", session.createDateTime(@Now());
```

following generates error / exceptions.

```
myDoc.replaceItemValue("ApprovedOn", @Now());
```

OR

```
var curr_Date = @Now();
myDoc.replaceItemValue("ApprovedOn", curr_Date);
```

OR

```
var mDt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(@Now());
myDoc.replaceItemValue("ApprovedOn", mDt.toJavaDate());
```

Error while executing JavaScript action expression

> Script interpreter error, line=168, col=17: [TypeError] Exception
>   occurred calling method NotesDocument.replaceItemValue(string, Date)
>   null

Please guide me how can I store current server date in a date and time field when any action is performed. Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: Are you sure myDoc is set correctly? The message said it's null.

Comment: I think it's because NotesDocument.replaceItemValue(string, Date) doesn't exist as a method, so the method is null, not the document.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers  Yes this is for both XPiNC and Web.Moreover the same function NotesDocument.replaceItemValue(string, Date)  works well when is session.createDateTime(@Now()) and stores client date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, SSJS can only run within the XPages runtime. For an XPages application accessed via a browser, the XPages runtime sits on top of the HTTP task on the server, so the date and time would be the server's. (That's why I asked the question above).

For setting a field value with the core Domino API, you need to pass a NotesDateTime. The NotesDocument SSJS class (mapping to the underlying Java Document class) doesn't allow you to pass a Java date. OpenNTF Domino API does allow you to pass a Java date and auto-converts the value.

Best approach for XPiNC (this came from Serdar Basegmez, I can't take credit) is access a server-based database in SSJS, call createDocument() method and access it's created date. In the getDatabase() method you'll have to explicitly name a server. This will have a performance impact, because XPiNC is running locally, so you're connecting from local to another server, but will work.

Comment: thanks for prompt support. do you mean same cod e wok perfectly fine on Web browser (mean server date and time) and return client time XPiNC right? How can I use OpenNTF Domino API to use server date and time in XPiNC. below statement is ok but sotres client date and time XPiNC myDoc.replaceItemValue("ApprovedOn", session.createDateTime(@Now());

Comment: ODA doesn't give any options for retrieving a server date, just for passing Java dates into a Notes Item.

Comment: thanks so no way I can get server date and time while executing SSJS code on XPiNC?

Comment: I've updated my original answer with a possible solution

Comment: thanks but I can create document on in same database in which I am working and will not save the document. will get  creation date of that document and will use the same in my code . Right?

Comment: I'm not sure if it treats that database as "local" or "on the server", but it should be easy for you to test

Comment: yes I tested and working perfectly fine. I really appreciate your help.  var mDoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();   myDoc.replaceItemValue("ApprovedOn", mDoc.getCreated()); stores server date and time and my old code saves client date and time. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it impossible to synchronize server and client (using NTP), so they both use the same date/time?

Comment: Yes doing the same but some issue with couple of machines which was creating the problem. Now fixed issue on code end as well looking the same thing for active directory.